SQLite3 ошибка при UPDATE
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Есть приложение написанное на Python для добавления книг в личную библиотеку с использованием Sqlite3. Есть модальное окно для изменения любой книги при её выборе путем выделения строки в виджете (см. скриншот), которое вставляет все данные о книге в окошко и пользователь может изменить необходимые ему поля. Однако при попытке сохранить результат, я получаю ошибку синтаксиса в Sqlite3, а именно: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Толкиен": syntax error. Такое же окно на добавление книги в базу через INSERT INTO работает. Вроде делаю всё по инструкции, не могу понять с чем это связано...
Переменные получения данных (используются также в INSERT INTO):
book_id = self.select_item[0]
book_author = entry_author.get()
book_title = entry_title.get()
book_year = spinbox_year.get()
select_status = combobox_status.get()
book_status = f'{1 if select_status == "В наличии" else 0}'

Запрос к базе данных на обновление строк:
cursor.execute(f'UPDATE Books SET author = {book_author}, title = {book_title}, year = {book_year} WHERE id = {book_id}')



Строки должны быть в кавычках, а ещё лучше — в параметрах

Это как? Попробовал несколько вариантов, что-то не вышло...

'UPDATE Books SET author = "{book_author}", title = "{book_title}", year = {book_year} WHERE id = {book_id}' или execute("UPDATE Books SET author = ?, title = ?, year = ? WHERE id = ?", (book_author, book_title, book_year, book_id))

Спасибо огромное, всё получилось! Я не правильно понял ваши слова. Через параметры лучше всего =)
